# Javascript, set allowable characters function

Tags: javascript

When I place the set “allowable characters function” into my javascript file the “window onload function” no longer works. Can anyone spot what might be wrong?

```
// --- ACTIVATES THE ON LOAD FUNCTION ---
    function init(){
        alert('ENTERED ON LOAD FUNCTION');
        myFunction_AlertThree();
    }

    window.onload = init; 

// ---> TESTING ONLY
    function myFunction_AlertThree() {
    alert('entered alert THREE function.');     
    }


//----------- SET ALLOWABLE CHARACTERS FUNCTION -----------     

    function inputLimiter(e,allow) {
        var AllowableCharacters = '';
        if (allow == 'Letters'{AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';}
        if (allow == 'Numbers'){AllowableCharacters='1234567890';}
        if (allow == 'NameCharacters'){AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -.\'';}
        if (allow == 'NameCharactersAndNumbers'){AllowableCharacters='1234567890 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-.\'';}
        if (allow == 'Currency'){AllowableCharacters='1234567890.';}

    var k = document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
        if (k!=13 && k!=8 && k!=0){
            if ((e.ctrlKey==false) && (e.altKey==false)) {
                return (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look in your [browser's console](https://kb.mailster.co/how-can-i-open-the-browsers-console/). Is there an error message?

Comment: Definitely is due to the missing `)`

Comment: Change `if (allow == 'Letters'{` to `if (allow == 'Letters'){`

Comment: @DaveNewton You got it. Add the answer, not a comment.

Comment: @OP This is why one-liners are so dangerous. Break it out into multiple lines for improved readability.

Comment: You may consider using [switch](http://mdn.io/switch) statement

Comment: @AymanSafadi Questions like this should just be closed as typos with a comment, not worth answering.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `)`

Change

```
if (allow == 'Letters'{AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';}
                     ^
                missing ) here
```

to

```
if (allow == 'Letters'){AllowableCharacters=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';}
                      ^
                 put it here
```

You should use your browser console for those errors because it'll show you where and what they are

Comment: The question should just be closed as a typo.